# Python type hint for undefined values to distinguish from None

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

I want to create a function signature where an `undefined` value and `None` are distinct from each other.

So e.g.:

```py
undefined = object()

def update(id: str, title: str = undefined, description: str):
    data = {
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
    }

    // remove undefined key-value pairs from data
    for key in data.keys():
        if data[key] is undefined:
            del data[key]
    
    # send data to the server for further processing
```

Obviously this way I get conflicting types and the following error: `Incompatible default for argument "description" (default has type "object", argument has type "str")`

From the above example it can be seen that passing `None` is completely valid as it will be replaced as the `null` value of JSON while if `undefined` is passed then the value won't be considered in the data.

I've tried to define undefined types like:

```py
UndefinedStr = typing.Union[str, undefined]
```

But I got the following error: `Variable "undefined" is not valid as a type`

I guess that's because `undefined` is an instance. So as a workaround I could do:

```py
class Undefined:
    pass

undefined = Undefined()

UndefinedStr = Union[str, Undefined]
```

This solution works, but to me feels a bit too broad.

So my question what is the best way to type hint this undefined use-case?

**UPDATE**:

Please don't focus on the fact that in the example the type of the `title` argument is `str`, the main intention behind this question is to find a universal type hint for a sentinel object that could be used in union with any other type.

In the meantime I've seen some progress on this specific issue within [PEP-0661](https://peps.python.org/pep-0661/), so seemingly this has become a broader topic to discuss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best proposal is provided by [PEP-661](https://peps.python.org/pep-0661/). Let's check that out and monitor it for a possible implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Your last attempt seems reasonable, but if you feel that creating a new type just to annotate a parameter with the type when you need just a single instance of it is too broad, you can use [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) to restrict the parameter to one specific object. Since `typing.Literal` takes only literals or `Enum` objects, a viable solution would be to create a singleton `Enum` class for the purpose:

```
from typing import Literal
from enum import Enum

Undefined = Enum('Undefined', ['undefined'])
undefined = Undefined.undefined

def update(id: str, title: str | Literal[Undefined.undefined] = undefined):
    ...
```

Demo of the code passing mypy: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=d44b405f144405354e380162df49ddbe

Comment: Why explicitly `Undefined.undefined` as argument to `Literal`, instead of just `undefined`?

Comment: That's what I tried at first, but mypy doesn't like it. Apparently `typing.Literal` has to be fed with literals/`Enum` objects directly, not through a variable assigned with the value of a literal/`Enum` object. Feel free to try it yourself.

Comment: Yeah I still don't think this is the best approach, and actually this is a rejected idea in PEP661: https://peps.python.org/pep-0661/#use-a-single-valued-enum

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved using NewType (https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NewType).
Combining this with one of your attempts, we could achieve the goal in the following way:

```
Undefined = typing.NewType('undefined', str)

UndefinedStr = typing.Union[str, Undefined]
```

And then defining the function using an instance of the new type;

```
undef = undefined('undefined')

def update(id: str, description: UndefinedStr = undef, title: str = 'title'):
```

This will work as a type hint for the static type checker. And at run time

```
if data[key] is undef # comparison with instance of str type, but will return True when data[key] = undef (@Brian's comment and doc of NewType).
```

Link to the demo code; https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=2b6e96a21a1eff30874cdf81938d8bdc

Comment: `if data[key] is undef # comparison with instance of type`, no, that's a comparison with an instance of `str`. NewType is a no-op at runtime. `undef` is just the string `"undefined"`. And thanks to string interning, runtime generated strings equal to``"undefined"` may also pass the `is` check.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right ! The type is str, will update the answer.

Comment: I like the look of this solution (reminiscent of Haskell newtypes), but I can't see that this actually offers anything over simply using `str` as-is, with a magical special value (as suggested by Mark Ransom). Which IMO is just too brittle.

Comment: Ahh, yes indeed, in this case a simple str with a special value does the trick (tried it out https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=4c965114422719e54aeeab7482d2e3fc). But, nevertheless was fun to learn about python's support for creating custom types.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `undefined` as a singleton and testing with `is`, the type and value don't really matter.  So why not make it a string?  I'd choose a value that is unmistakably invalid so you can catch it if a later bug lets it slip through.

```
undefined = 'undefined ' * 10
```

Comment: This is a question about static type hinting, but there is no mention of type hints in this answer. Do you mean to suggest using a `Literal`?

Comment: @Brian61354270 the question is about eliminating an error because the default is the wrong type.  Instead of going through gyrations to allow two different types in the hint, just make the default object the correct type as specified by the hint.

Comment: In this case wouldn't it make more sense to use a static uid instead of a not too unique string?

Comment: @Szabolcs because of the way it's being used, the content actually doesn't matter. I was going for something obvious in case a bug resulted in the string getting through.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is to allow for `{'title': None}` if the incoming JSON specifically includes `{"title": null}` - if the JSON does not include a `"title"` key, you don't want it in your outgoing data.

I see three good options.

## 1 - Make the decision in the function

An "undefined" title is an edge case - make a child string class to define this edge case.

```py
class Undefined(str):
    pass


def update(id: str, title: str = Undefined(), description: str):
    data = {
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
    }

    // remove undefined key-value pairs from data
    for key in data.keys():
        if isinstance(data[key], Undefined):
            del data[key]
    
    # send data to the server for further processing
```

Since `Undefined` is an instance of the `str` class, your type hint is still valid. There is also no chance for accidentally removing a valid title (even if that title is an empty string or `null`).

## 2 - Make the decision in the caller with flavored functions

There are two flavors of update - one includes a title, one does not. You can create two separate update functions to show this.

```py
def update(id: str, description: str):
    data = {
        "description": description,
    }
    sendData(id, data)


def updateWithTitle(id: str, title: str, description: str):
    data = {
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
    }
    sendData(id, data)


def sendData(id: str, data: dict):
    # send data to the server for further processing
```

This has all of the good of the first option, but it also removes the mutation of data. The caller is left to determine whether or not the data sent to the server should include a title (even one that is `null`).

## 3 - Make the decision in the caller with the Builder pattern

Sometimes you want a title, sometimes you don't. This is a classic use-case for the [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern.

```py
class Data:
    def __init__(self, id: str, description: str):
        self._data = {
            'id': id,
            'description': description,
        }

    def withTitle(self, title: str):
        self._data['title'] = title
        return self

    def send(self):
        # send data to the server for further processing


Data('an id', 'a desc').send()
Data('an id', 'a desc').withTitle('the title').send()
Data('an id', 'a desc').withTitle(None).send()
```

This option makes it clear that the title is optional (and can even be `None`, or `null` from JSON), and provides further separation of concerns, although you do reintroduce mutation (additive this time instead of subtractive, which is better for performance).

Comment: Awarding the bounty to this answer for effort and some good general ideas, but I think [blhsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75646557/745903) is still best addressing the gist of the question.

Comment: I didn't really ask for this to be honest. My intention is to find a generic sentinel value that can be recognized by python's type checkers.